# Audio stream from PC without sound card to Iphone

Tags: audio, iphone, streaming, desktop-computer

I have pc without sound card (HP Proliant Microserver) and Iphone 4. They are connected by Wi-Fi. Can I stream audio from PC to Iphone somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the PC isnt the one actualy playing the music, you should be able to do it without a soundcard.

I've used Air Playit myself, and it works flawlessly. With the right configuration, the devices dosent even need to be on the same network.

Air Playit - http://www.airplayit.com/streaming-music.htm

Regards,

Patrick

Comment: Yeah, it working. But i want to stream live audio (from cinema or internet) and it not helps to me.